# Format change problem when assigning json to variable

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, swagger, file-format

i have json file like below and i want to assign it to a variable.

```
const swRouter = {
    "/posts": {
        "get": {
        },
        "post": {
        }
    }
}
```

But quotes disappear when i print:

```
{
    /posts: {
       get:(0) {
       },
       post:(0) {
       }
    }
}
```

what i tried:
i used `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` but nothing has changed ,the output was exactly the same.

Comment: *"But quotes disappear when I print"* - print where and how? Print to the browser console using `console.log()`?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might be the chrome dev tools consoles console.log which serializes variables when printing. Try logging with console.dir and it might help.

If that's not the case please add more info to your question. I really cannot figure out what you mean by quotes disappearing. JS objects don't need quotes and the first snippet isn't even JSON it's just a js object